XSLT match entry in another XML node and return a corresponding element
Disclaimer: I'm still learning XML / XSLT, so apologies if this is simple.
I'm trying to look up an element in node A, match it to a similar element in node B, and return an entry from node B to node A.
i.e. find the startDate under EmployeeTimeSheetEntry that matches EmployeeTimeValuationResult/bookingDate, and return the corresponding cust_Overtime_HR_Action element:

I'm trying to use a key to generate a lookup (based on the answer to this question: Print comma separated tokens when they have been looked up in another node), but I'm very unclear as to where to put the apply-templates statement to go and retrieve the node (and I'm very much confusing myself now, going round in circles).
Sample source XML:
<EmployeeTimeSheet>
<EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
      <startDate>2024-11-25T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
      <startDate>2024-11-27T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
      <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>Payout</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
      <startDate>2024-11-30T00:00:00.000</startDate>
    </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
  </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
  <employeeTimeValuationResult>
    <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-25T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
    </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
  </employeeTimeValuationResult>
</EmployeeTimeSheet>

And this is what I'm trying (and failing) to do in XSLT:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<!-- generate lookup table - must be top level, i.e. before template match -->
<xsl:key name="timeSheetEntry" match="EmployeeTimeSheet/EmployeeTimeSheet/employeeTimeSheetEntry/EmployeeTimeSheetEntry" use="startDate"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<EmployeeTimeSheet>

<!-- retrieve cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION where the bookingDate matches the startDate in above lookup -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('timeSheetEntry', EmployeeTimeSheet/EmployeeTimeSheet/employeeTimeValuationResult/EmployeeTimeValuationResult/bookingDate)/cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION"/>
</xsl:template>
    <xsl:for-each select="EmployeeTimeSheet/EmployeeTimeSheet">
        <xsl:for-each select="employeeTimeValuationResult/EmployeeTimeValuationResult">
            <xsl:variable name="var_TimeValResult" select="./*"></xsl:variable>
                <EmployeeTimeSheet>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$var_TimeValResult"/>
                    
                    <xsl:template match="cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION"> 
                    <overtimeHRaction>                  
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </overtimeHRaction> 
                    </xsl:template> 
                    
                </EmployeeTimeSheet>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>  <!-- EmployeeTimeSheet/EmployeeTimeSheet -->
</EmployeeTimeSheet> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
(apologies for beginner level code)
The output should look like this, with the element cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION for 2024-11-25 added to the EmployeeTimeValuationResult node:
<EmployeeTimeSheet>
<EmployeeTimeSheet>
  <employeeTimeValuationResult>
    <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-25T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
      <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
    </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
  </employeeTimeValuationResult>
</EmployeeTimeSheet>

Can anyone please advise where I'm going wrong? An XSLT test tool just says:
Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation
I can't figure out the logic required for the retrieval of the corresponding node.
Many thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.
Kind regards,
AJ

Which is the result you want your XSLT to output, which is the result or error you get? Please edit your question and show those details. Consider to provide us minimal but complete samples of XML and XSLT to reproduce the result you get.

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
All within the question as text, no images.

Apologies both, I'm still relatively new to this. I've simplified the source XML and included the full XSLT (which is not working btw, that's my issue), and I've provided a sample of what the output should look like. I hope this is sufficient / appropriate. Really appreciate the feedback - will try to do better.

Consider this simplified example:
XML
<EmployeeTimeSheet>
    <employeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
            <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
            <startDate>2024-11-25T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
            <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
            <startDate>2024-11-27T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
        <EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
            <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>Payout</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
            <startDate>2024-11-30T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmployeeTimeSheetEntry>
    </employeeTimeSheetEntry>
    <employeeTimeValuationResult>
        <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
            <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
            <hours>9</hours>
            <externalCode>ad0a255f256d44ddbe41bc6ab1d632b9</externalCode>
            <entityUUID>6CB3BB8B01C4434FABD28A84554B6A88</entityUUID>
            <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
            <bookingDate>2024-11-25T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
            <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
        </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
        <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
            <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
            <hours>9</hours>
            <externalCode>ee32afbee0e1452fbdcc21e9ee9e45e5</externalCode>
            <entityUUID>397C8AED082B4B5192941FF6D02C29FA</entityUUID>
            <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
            <bookingDate>2024-11-26T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
            <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
        </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
        <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
            <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
            <hours>6.5</hours>
            <externalCode>6d84652c40bb49c7b028fda128802100</externalCode>
            <entityUUID>73F775BAF8EA43F3BE011EB0C34601E5</entityUUID>
            <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
            <bookingDate>2024-11-27T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
            <hoursAndMinutes>6:30</hoursAndMinutes>
        </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
        <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
            <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
            <hours>9</hours>
            <externalCode>1527b80a2ccf4c409e9549bb22b0da20</externalCode>
            <entityUUID>1397BD090FC0477C8C9EABE8B15939D2</entityUUID>
            <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
            <bookingDate>2024-11-28T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
            <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
        </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
        <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
            <timeTypeGroup>TFX_ABSENCES_TTG</timeTypeGroup>
            <hours>2.5</hours>
            <externalCode>e2092ce1a0c6498fadc6d4caa0836ef1</externalCode>
            <entityUUID>A996867E64B9422FBC1765662286B633</entityUUID>
            <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
            <bookingDate>2024-11-27T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
            <hoursAndMinutes>2:30</hoursAndMinutes>
        </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
        <EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
            <timeTypeGroup>TFX_ABSENCES_TTG</timeTypeGroup>
            <hours>9</hours>
            <externalCode>50745ba2f6c241fc925a666aef955a50</externalCode>
            <entityUUID>65D732D727E346B79E60318C4703910C</entityUUID>
            <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
            <bookingDate>2024-11-29T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
            <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
        </EmployeeTimeValuationResult>
    </employeeTimeValuationResult>
</EmployeeTimeSheet>

XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="EmployeeTimeSheetEntry" use="startDate" />

<xsl:template match="/EmployeeTimeSheet">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="employeeTimeValuationResult/EmployeeTimeValuationResult">
            <result>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('k1', bookingDate)/cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION"/>
            </result>           
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Result
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <result>
      <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
      <hours>9</hours>
      <externalCode>ad0a255f256d44ddbe41bc6ab1d632b9</externalCode>
      <entityUUID>6CB3BB8B01C4434FABD28A84554B6A88</entityUUID>
      <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-25T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
      <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
      <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
   </result>
   <result>
      <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
      <hours>9</hours>
      <externalCode>ee32afbee0e1452fbdcc21e9ee9e45e5</externalCode>
      <entityUUID>397C8AED082B4B5192941FF6D02C29FA</entityUUID>
      <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-26T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
      <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
   </result>
   <result>
      <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
      <hours>6.5</hours>
      <externalCode>6d84652c40bb49c7b028fda128802100</externalCode>
      <entityUUID>73F775BAF8EA43F3BE011EB0C34601E5</entityUUID>
      <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-27T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
      <hoursAndMinutes>6:30</hoursAndMinutes>
      <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
   </result>
   <result>
      <timeTypeGroup>SCHED_WORK_TIME_A</timeTypeGroup>
      <hours>9</hours>
      <externalCode>1527b80a2ccf4c409e9549bb22b0da20</externalCode>
      <entityUUID>1397BD090FC0477C8C9EABE8B15939D2</entityUUID>
      <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-28T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
      <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
   </result>
   <result>
      <timeTypeGroup>TFX_ABSENCES_TTG</timeTypeGroup>
      <hours>2.5</hours>
      <externalCode>e2092ce1a0c6498fadc6d4caa0836ef1</externalCode>
      <entityUUID>A996867E64B9422FBC1765662286B633</entityUUID>
      <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-27T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
      <hoursAndMinutes>2:30</hoursAndMinutes>
      <cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>TOIL</cust_Overtime_HR_ACTION>
   </result>
   <result>
      <timeTypeGroup>TFX_ABSENCES_TTG</timeTypeGroup>
      <hours>9</hours>
      <externalCode>50745ba2f6c241fc925a666aef955a50</externalCode>
      <entityUUID>65D732D727E346B79E60318C4703910C</entityUUID>
      <EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>dd70365f71084e63b1143d4c40bd40a9</EmployeeTimeSheet_externalCode>
      <bookingDate>2024-11-29T00:00:00.000</bookingDate>
      <hoursAndMinutes>9:00</hoursAndMinutes>
   </result>
</results>


Many thanks Michael, I just saw your response after I had finished updating the question based on other feedback. I will take a look and try to understand the solution, but this looks exactly like what I need. Thank you so much for the guidance.

Recommended reading: https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html

Michael, this has worked brilliantly. Thank you so much.

QQ (sorry!). As the key has to be at the top level, how would I deal with multiple  entries that each have their own  and  nodes?
Is there a way to create a key for-each ?

e.g.

 




 





Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and add it there. Or ask a new one if the problem is sufficiently different.

Apologies - will do so.

I've now raised a separate question. Thanks again Michael.
